# How can I calculate time-varying Value at Risk (VaR) and Conditional VaR for return series?

Tags: r, time-series, garch, risk

I am working on ABT index and I calculated the return series. Also, I intend to fit a `GARCH(1,1)` model to the return series and then calculate the VaR and CVaR as the following image:
[image]

I used many approaches and as far as I know, the VaR and CVaR are one value per series. I do not understand the time-varying VaR/CVaR. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A GARCH model specifies the entire conditional distribution of a time series $\{x_t\}$ at each time point. E.g. an ARMA(p,q)-GARCH(r,s) model looks like this:
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= c + \varphi_1 x_{t-1} + \dots + \varphi_p x_{t-p} + \theta_1 u_{t-1} + \dots + \theta_q u_{t-q}, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \alpha_s u_{t-s}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dots + \beta_r \sigma_{t-r}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.D(0,1),
\end{aligned}
where $D$ is some probability distribution with zero mean and unit variance. Thus the distribution of $x_t$ is $D(0,1)$ scaled by $\sigma_t$ and shifted by $\mu_t$.

Knowing the distribution, you can extract VaR and CVaR. You can do this analytically or by simulation. In the latter case, you generate a large number of realizations from the distribution of the time point of interest and obtain the empirical VaR and CVaR.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I am going to use the simulation for the job and did not completely follow your point. Can you please elaborate with some examples preferably in code or formula?

Comment: @Afshin, see the update.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still do not understand what this means `...from the distribution of the time point...`? Can you give me some idea about how to perform it by simulation please?

Comment: @Afshin, take the distribution $D(0,1)$, simulate $n$ realizations, multiply them by $\sigma_t$ and add $\mu_t$. That will correspond to a simulation of $n$ realizations of $x_t$.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Afshin, if the answer solves your problem, you may accept is by clicking on the tick mark to the left. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not use it. Can you provide some example regarding the problem please?

Comment: @Afshin, have you figured it out?